# Conditional probability problem for 5 red balls and 5 blue balls in a bag

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

A bag contains 5 red balls and 5 blue balls. Three balls are drawn randomly without replacement.
Find: the conditional probability of drawing at least 1 blue ball if we had already drew at least one red ball.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show your workings or thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307378/decision-tree-for-conditonal-probability-balls-question help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decision tree for conditonal probability balls question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307378/decision-tree-for-conditonal-probability-balls-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⚠️ I wrote this assuming that you are not satisfied with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307378/decision-tree-for-conditonal-probability-balls-question) answer and want a different answer
️ This answer is with a different approach and **may be wrong**.

Probability = 2/3

According to the condition, 
it is fixed that we had already drawn a red ball.
So we can say that - now we are left only with the possible combination from 2 balls.
These 2 balls can be in combination of

- red-blue (or blue-red both are same)
- red-red
- blue-blue

  **Only in 2 out of 3 combinations, we get at least 1 blue ball**. 
  (Just don't forget that we are ignoring the 3rd ball as it is already been told that it is red.)

Comment: This is a decent start, but unfortunately the probabilities for getting red-blue, red-red, blue-blue are different, so the answer is not $\frac{2}{3}$, the same way the probability of flipping a coin twice and getting one head and one tail is not $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @TonyIp I agree with you. But there is a difference between flipping 2 coins at once and flipping a coin twice. When we flip 2 coins at once, the order is (generally) not important. In the question, all the balls are drawn at once, so I don't think that the order (as red-blue or blue-red) is important. If I am missing anything please do let me know. 